# Why when opening any text editor in raspbian through ssh connection hangs?

Tags: ssh, vpn, raspbian, mikrotik

I have clean installation of raspbian on raspberry pi 3. Because of not working port forwarding in router I configured auto connection on raspbian to my VPN server on mikrotik router.

I used this tutorial for configuring VPN on mikrotik router: https://support.purevpn.com/mikrotik-configuration

And configured VPN client on raspberry by this tutorial: https://prosindo.com/blog/2015/08/24/vpn-pptp-client-on-raspberry-pi/

Currently I can connect to raspberry through ssh (from windows 10) and use commands cd, ls, cat, but when I try to open mc (midnight commander), nano, vim or htop connection hangs and I can't do anything, even commands Ctrl + C and Ctrl + Z don't work.

For connecting to raspberry I use ssh client installed with git:
`ssh 192.168.99.102 -l pi` Also tried putty.

How can I debug or fix this problem in my situation?

What I see when run mc command:

[image: mc output]

Comment: What is the output of `echo "$TERM"` after you connect? If it's depends on the local client (`ssh` vs PuTTY) then please provide both outputs.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski 
ssh: cygwin,
putty: xterm

Comment: Do you see the rpi trying to send a large packet over and over? Do you have any firewall rules that would block ICMP? This really sounds like a PMTUD issue...